# Error BLE gattool with handle input - What is wrong?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to write a value in a BLE device.

```
sudo gatttool  -b 34:14:B5:4A:20:75 --char-write-req -a 36F5 -n ee83b36835181e5ef206f5ac3a708ec7
```

Problem is it doesn't recognize the UUID/handle "36F5", while this has to be the right handle as I sniffed it with nRF. Adding "0x" before the "36F5" also doesn't work.

Error ssh:

[image]

If I enter the value (ee83b36835181e5ef206f5ac3a708ec7) in nRF, everything works fine.

Screenshot nRF:

[image]

Comment: `gatttool` was [deprecated](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?id=b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617) back in 2017. The current tool for generic Bluetooth Low Energy scanning and exploration on Linux is `bluetoothctl`

Comment: @ukBaz is it also possible to do a write command? can find anything...

Comment: Inside `bluetoothctl` you need to type `menu gatt`. Then select the gatt UUID you want to read and write.

Comment: Error Domain=CBATTErrorDomain Code=1 "The handle is invalid." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The handle is invalid.} I am getting this error